# Casting a DataFrame into a function doesn't change the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

new to programming and Python in general, so I'm still learning. I'm trying to write a script that takes our tickets and breaks them down by hour and day of the week. We often have no calls come in through late evening/early morning hours, so I've written the following to add missing hours to a pivoted DataFrame I made:

```
hours = [*range(24)]
dt_count_pivot = dt_count_pivot.reindex(columns=hours).fillna(0.0)
dt_hours_pivot = dt_hours_pivot.reindex(columns=hours).fillna(0.0)
```

I'd like to write a function instead:

```
def missing_hours(x):
    hours = [*range(24)]
    x = x.reindex(columns=hours).fillna(0.0)
```

But when I cast the name of either one of those DataFrames as the variable in the function, no changes are made.

Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the dataframe at the end of the function.

```
def missing_hours(x):
    hours = [*range(24)]
    x = x.reindex(columns=hours).fillna(0.0)
    return x
```

And then you call the function as so:

```
dt_count_pivot = missing_hours(dt_count_pivot)
```

Comment: That did it! That return portion of the function was what I needed. Thanks a million, Alan!